# Is 'walked' the correct tense in this paragraph?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, past-participles

The next folder she opened contained something that neither of them had expected: five photos of Emily’s brother. They had been taken while James walked through a glass door.

Comment: Helo and welcome to the site! Please note: a) always include a few thoughts of your own - why do you think "walked" is correct or if not, what would be your suggestion? b) When quoting a text, always give the source / author, perhaps a link and usually it is marked as quote with a '>' before each paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the second sentence is grammatically incorrect in the technical sense, but it is a bit awkward. The word "while" implies that the action following it (James walked through a glass door) will be continuous: you might say "when something happened," but when you say "while something happened," it implies that that "something" took a noteworthy amount of time to happen. You might think of examples like "...while they walked in the park," or "while she was reading." But the action "walked through a glass door" does not have that same character - it seems to be an instantaneous action, like "picked up his hairbrush" or "sneezed." It seems to me that there are a few ways you could fix the awkwardness:

"They were taken when James walked through a glass door." (This implies that the pictures were taken after James walked through the door - and perhaps as a result of it - so this is probably not what you mean.)

They had been taken while James was walking through a glass door. (Most readers will think this implies that James took a while to walk through that door, which might be how you envision the situation.)

"They had been taken right as James walked through a glass door." (I think the phrase "right as" helps you out here by implying the sort of instantaneous action that I imagine you are going for, so that you are free to choose either form of "walk" as suits your preferences. So this last one is my personal preference...)

"They had been taken right as James was walking through a glass door."

Comment: Yes. The impression I had was of an automatic series of photos like the kinds that many cameras will take over the space of a second or so, fast enough to capture motion in progress.